# How to display laptop charging speed

Tags: usb, power-management

I have a laptop that charges via USB-C (fifth generation Thinkpad X1 with Ubuntu) and it can be charged by connecting it to the USB-C port of my desktop. But I would like to know at which wattage it is charging.

Is there a command to display at which wattage a laptop is currently charging? This would also be helpful to compare different combinations of charging bricks and USB cables.

Comment: The easiest way is to add a hardware voltage/amp/watt measurement device between USB-C & device; they are very cheap; and will display a real/just measurement instead  of a software based one if it is possible *(I 'm not sure software measurement is possible on USB from the laptop)*

Comment: @francoisP"Between USB and device"? So would that be something that has two USB ports and I connect one to the laptop and the other to the charger? Won't that confuse the smart USB cables which negotiate voltage between device and charger?

Comment: things like [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=voltage+mesure+USB+-+USB) depending on you needs of course